# Dataproc batch constraint violation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

In my project, the **constraints/compute.requireOsLogin** policy constraint is enabled.
If I try running a dataproc batch job using this command:

```
gcloud dataproc batches submit --project <project-id> --region us-east1 pyspark --batch batch-123 gs://mybucket/test.py --version 2.1  --subnet test
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.batches.submit.pyspark) Batch job is FAILED. Detail: Constraint constraints/compute.requireOsLogin violated for project 123456789.
```

The subnet has Private Google Access enabled. The test.py file can be anything, I took the example from [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-google-dataproc/).

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [setup OS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/manage-oslogin-in-an-org#set-org-policy) login in your orginzation that will enable OS login to the newly created VMs, But OS Login in Dataproc Serverless is not supported. See list of not supported products below:

> - Cloud Data Fusion versions 6.1.4 and earlier
> - Cloud Composer Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) public clusters that run versions earlier than 1.23.5
> - GKE private clusters that run node pool versions earlier than 1.20.5
> - Dataproc Serverless
> - Windows Server and SQL Server VMs
> - Fedora CoreOS VMs. To manage instance access to VMs created using these images, use the Fedora CoreOS ignition system

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/manage-oslogin-in-an-org#limitations

Answer (score 1):

I think dataproc batches use Dataproc Serverless, which manages VMs themselves and hence OS Login is disabled. If you create a Dataproc GCE cluster and submit the job, I think this should work.

Comment: So there is no way to use serverless with this policy?